# jquery set background color with variable

Tags: php, jquery

I want to set background color based on user preference that's in a database.

I set a variable named $bc from the session variable I saved from the row.

If I echo the either the session variable ($_SESSION['backcolr']) or the new variable ($bc), the correct value of yellow appears.  However, if I try to use either variable with jQuery, it doesn't work.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //  $('#body').css(background-color','yellow')  -- this works
    $("body").css("background-color",'$bc');     --- this doesn't work
</script>
```

Comment: you need to `echo` it out

Answer (score 1):

Hello you should modify your code like below;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //  $('#body').css(background-color','yellow')  -- this works
    $("body").css("background-color",'<?PHP echo $bc; ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  It's working now  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you need to tell PHP when it should be parsing PHP code.
Replace that line with:

```
$("body").css("background-color",'<?php echo $bc; ?>');
```